# Merging two arrays without any duplicates [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net

**The question being asked is as follows:**

Implement the UniqueNames method. When passed two arrays of names, it will return an array containing the names that appear in either or both arrays. The returned array should have no duplicates.

For example, calling MergeNames.UniqueNames({'Ava', 'Emma', 'Olivia'}, {'Olivia', 'Sophia', 'Emma'}) should return an array containing Ava, Emma, Olivia, and Sophia in any order.

**Starting Code:**

```
   Module Module1
       Public Class MergeNames
           Public Shared Function UniqueNames(names1() As String, names2() As  String) As String()
               Throw New NotImplementedException()
           End Function
       End Class

       Public Sub Main()
           Dim names1() As String = {"Ava", "Emma", "Olivia"}
           Dim names2() As String = {"Olivia", "Sophia", "Emma"}
           Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", MergeNames.UniqueNames(names1, names2))) ' should print Ava, Emma, Olivia, Sophia
       End Sub
   End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ would be the easiest way to go here:

```
Dim combinedUniqueNames = names1.Union(names2).Distinct().ToArray()
```

`Union` will combine two lists, `Distinct` will remove duplicates and `ToArray` creates a new array from the result.  As is pretty much always the case with LINQ extension methods, they can all be called on any `IEnumerable(Of T)`.  Your `String` arrays implement `IEnumerable(Of String)`.

EDIT:

As per Jimi's comment, we just need:

```
Dim combinedUniqueNames = names1.Union(names2).ToArray()
```

I guess I should have realised, given that 'union' is a set operation and does exclude duplicates in a mathematical context.

Comment: No need for `Distinct`.

Comment: Remarks sections of the [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union) methods: *This method excludes duplicates from the return set*. `Concat()` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MergeNames {

```
public static String[] uniqueNames(String[] names1, String[] names2) {
        List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String name: names1) {
        if(!list.contains(name)) {
            list.add(name);
        }
    }
    for (String name: names2) {
        if(!list.contains(name)) {
            list.add(name);
        }
    }
    String[] a= list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    return a;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names1 = new String[] {"Ava", "Emma", "Emma","Olivia"};
    String[] names2 = new String[] {"Olivia", "Sophia", "Emma"};
    System.out.println(String.join(", ", MergeNames.uniqueNames(names1, names2))); // should print Ava, Emma, Olivia, Sophia
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.